# Windows Server VMs have incorrect time on boot (Esxi 6.7.0 Update 3)

Tags: vmware-esxi, ntp, time, windows-server-2019

We run ESXI 6.7.0 Update 3 (Build 14320388).
The Windows 2019 VMs running on that host, when they boot, their time is incorrect.
I have to manually open the Windows settings and set off and back on the "Set time automatically" so the time gets correct.

Comment: **Is this a bug?** - No, it isn't a bug. I wish people would stop asking that every time they encounter a problem. It's almost never a bug. Is the host time correct? Where does the host sync it's time from? Are the virtual machines Windows computers? If so, are they joined to an Active Directory Domain?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by time on the host being wrong (fix this by configuring time sync on the host) and maybe the option to `Synchronize guest time with host` is set under VM Settings -> VM Options -> VM Tools.

Alternatively, if the option isn't set, it's just because the VM reboots, you need to provide time synchronization inside the VM using Windows Time or NTP.